# UITableView doesn't display content properly in simulator(retina 4 inch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I have setup three prototype cells as shown in screenshot below.However when I run the app , all the elements like labels and imageView doesn't show up properly.I have designed these things in prototype cells in storyboard , using dragging and dropping appropriate elements at the desired positions and haven't added any code such as `heightForRow`.I have also checked Simulated Metrics which is set for Retina 4 inch.What am I doing wrong?

Designed as below.

[image: prototype cell]

And the following displays on the simulator.

[image: display]

Comment: can you send the body of `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}`

Comment: Can you return the appropriate row size in the delegate method?- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return yourHeight;
}

Comment: @sbarow If you think this is the correct solution then make it "This comment adds something useful to this post". It helps others

Comment: Can't we design these things without writing code?...Because I have followed the same approach.

Comment: Appropriate height should be returned in the delegate method otherwise default row height will overwrite your custom height...

Answer (score 2):

Implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` correctly and also check your delegate config`(tblview.delegate = self)`

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
      return row1Height;
   else if(...).
   .
   .
   .
   else 
      return defaultHeight;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you return the appropriate row size in the delegate method?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    return yourHeight;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"Cell3";



    // Configure the cell...
    if([indexPath row] == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //cell.textlabel = @"YourText";
        //
    }

    if([indexPath row] == 1)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //cell.textlabel = @"YourText";
        //
    }

    if([indexPath row] == 2)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier3 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //cell.textlabel = @"YourText";
        //
    }
```

Comment: I think, Nothing to be change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Because cell is populate with correct data as well view. but height should adjust with according to rows.

Comment: Ok, make sure you are using the correct return for the method- `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ return heightValue; }`